# Evento al darle clic en celda de una tabla

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentando generar dos eventos al darle clic a diferentes celdas dentro de un GridView. El problema que si ejecuto el evento en la primer celda se dispara el evento 1, en cambio si ejecuto el evento de la celda 2 se dispara el evento 1 y evento 2.

Traté de replicar el problema en el siguiente código.

```js
$("table[id*='GrdDatos'] a[id*=GetId]").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
  if ($(e.currentTarget).is('a[id*=GetId]')) {
    alert(1);
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
$("table[id*='GrdDatos'] a[id*=GetIdOtEliminar]").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
  if ($(e.currentTarget).is('a[id*=GetIdOtEliminar]')) {
    alert(2);
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%" id="GrdDatos">
  <tr>
    <th>Evento 1</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Evento 2</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a id="GetId" style="cursor:pointer">Clic aquí 1</a></td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td><a id="GetIdOtEliminar" style="cursor:pointer">Clic aquí 2</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Por su ayuda muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás usando el selector `a[id*=GetId]`, que significa "elementos `a` que tienen un `id` **que empieza por** `GetId`.

Si quitas el asterisco, busca que **exactamente** el valor sea `GetId`:

```js
$("table[id*='GrdDatos'] a[id*=GetId]").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
  if ($(e.currentTarget).is('a[id=GetId]')) {
    alert(1);
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
$("table[id='GrdDatos'] a[id=GetIdOtEliminar]").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
  if ($(e.currentTarget).is('a[id=GetIdOtEliminar]')) {
    alert(2);
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%" id="GrdDatos">
  <tr>
    <th>Evento 1</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Evento 2</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a id="GetId" style="cursor:pointer">Clic aquí 1</a></td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td><a id="GetIdOtEliminar" style="cursor:pointer">Clic aquí 2</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```